# Reading data of selected row in grid

Tags: acumatica

With button click if I am using PXAdapter I am able to read the main master data but it is not reading of the selected grid. For Example, in the Case screen if I want to get the data of selected row in Activities tab, how can I achieve that. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With below code you can get the currently selected row from the grid

```
Base.Activities.Current
```

Comment: I'm not sure .Current is set in all cases. I think there's a flag that you need to set in the ASPX to have current value synchronized when you invoke the action.

Comment: You can set SyncPosition = true in the grid